# Laravel Project - Postman escaping characters

Tags: php, laravel, postman

I have a Laravel project API and am trying to run a query in postman that previously worked, the data I am sending in a POST request is..

```
{"hash":"sdf74","name":"john","age":"33","timestamp","1538565163"}
```

When I read the data back in Laravel it has escaped all of the quotes so it looks like this...

```
{\"hash\":\"sdf74\",\"name\":\"john\",\"age\":\"33\",\"timestamp\",\"1538565163\"}
```

I am fairly certain this didn't happen previously, is there a way to disable this escaping within Postman?

Answer (score 0):

You can escape these characters with `stripcslashes()` function.

> Returns a string with backslashes stripped off. Recognizes C-like \n, \r ..., octal and hexadecimal representation.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripcslashes.php

Answer (score 0):

use JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES

```
json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: As these are only being generated when a request is made through postman, will it still work if there are no slashes?